# Making API calls via Detox tests

Tags: javascript, cors, axios, detox

I was trying to get Detox to make a network call during test script execution so I installed axios. When I run my code in a separate node script I can hit my endpoint no problem on the network. When I run that code within Detox I get an error saying `Cross origin null forbidden`. I have checked headers and have verified that I can hit the server with a curl from my terminal and also that standalone script also retrieves data fine.

I have even tried setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the headers and the new error is now`Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`

Has anyone attempted this type of action before in this scenario or can someone help me to understand what is happening here?

Comment: I have a hunch this might be realted to the environment your test runner sets up for you. If you use jest, set the environment as node.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is an Axios issue. I found this: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1358

Looks like it might be because Axios uses `XMLHttpRequest`. I did the same implementation with `node-fetch` and it works fine.